# Texas Instruments ADC - Input Clock

Tags: texas-instruments

I have a question regarding the ADCs **ADS58B19** inputclock, this ADC can be clocked with LVDS.
The data sheet says that Vpp = 700mV, which is +-350mV. The ADCs Vcm = 1.7V, is this the in and output Vcm?
Is it possible to clock the ADC with a Vpp = 700mV and Vcm = 1V?

Datasheet: https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ads58b19.pdf?ts=1602577981307&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FADS58B19

Clock Specifications on page 3.

Thanks

Comment: Notice on page 47: "This setting allows the use of ... ac-coupling for LVPECL and LVDS clock sources". So the vendor recommendation is to AC couple LVDS clock inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *The ADCs Vcm = 1.7V, is this the in and output Vcm?*

Vcm is an output voltage and can be used to bias the clock inputs if only a single ended clock is used (see figure 64 below). The clock signal is then fed via a capacitor. For full differential clocks you don't need to bias (figure 65): -

[image]

> *Is it possible to clock the ADC with a Vpp = 700mV and Vcm = 1V?*

I don't believe that would work.

Answer (score 0):

On page 47 it says that Vcm for the input clock = 1.7V. So using a clock with Vcm = 1V will be bad.

Comment: If you're not posting this as an answer to your own question then you have misunderstood how SE works. Please take the [Tour](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour). This is a Q&A site rather than a forum.